# Matrix and eigenvalues with determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

if given that the determinant of a 3 by 3 matrix with only one real entries is 82 and an eigenvalue is given to be 4+5i, what are the other eigenvalues?
Since the determinant is a non zero number, I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this problem? If so, please explain what you have tried in the body of your question.

Comment: I am confused since the determinant is not zero. I have not done these kinds of questions.

Comment: Do you know any properties of the determinant as it relates to eigenvalues? Or properties of the eigenvalues when the matrix has all real entries?

Comment: Yes, I am currently in linear algebra land just learned about that.

Comment: What properties did you learn that you think might be helpful?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial has real coefficients. If one of its roots is complex, what can you say about its other roots?

Comment: If you know the (nonzero) determinant of this matrix then any list of n−1 nonzero values could be eigenvalues

Comment: The diagonal has to be a number minus lambda I know

Comment: @Madison: if you place a bounty on this question, you will get a fully detailed answer in no time ;)

Comment: @phaedo I cant because I have just posted this question

Comment: ok fine, here is hint #1: if 4 + 5i is eigenvalue, what can you say about the conjugate 4 - 5i?

Comment: @phaedo In order to find the complex conjugate, you just reverse the sign of the imaginary part of the number. So it would be 4+5i

Comment: the conjugate of (4+5i) = 4-5i,  now show that (4-5i) must be an eigenvalue of your real 3x3 matrix A

Comment: @phaedo So, my other eigenvalue would be 4-5i?

Comment: you need to prove it, then you have to find the third eigenvalue...

Comment: @phaedo How do you find the third eigenvalue?

Comment: I think a simple google search about properties of determinants in relation to eigenvalues will help you here

Comment: @phaedo I have tried. The determinate is a nonzero number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a 3x3 real matrix has up to 3 eigenvalues, since one of them is known to be complex, its conjugate is also an eigenvalue
the third eigenvalue x must be real
the determinant equals the product of eigenvalues
Therefore (4+5i)*(4-5i)*x = 82
Solve for x, you're done

Comment: A $3\times3$ real matrix has *exactly* three eigenvalues (counting with multiplicity).

Comment: So I got lambda=78/25-4/5i. Is that correct?

Comment: No, you should expand  (4+5i)*(4-5i) and you will get a real number...  Recall $(a + b)(a - b) = a^2 - b^2$